# Force global variable to refresh

Tags: python, environment-variables

I have a python script in which it has a global variable as follows:
`PROJ = os.getenv('PROJ')` that I run in a software to execute the script.

Say if the initial value of `PROJ` is `POP` and if I change the value via a UI to `LOL`, when I run my script, I had expected `PROJ` to be `LOL` but it turns out to be `POP`

Is there any way in which I can force this global variable to refresh or recall it somehow?

Answer (score 4):

I don't really think this is a Python issue.   Instead, it is an operating system issue.

In general, processes only see the environment at the time of their creation and they don't receive updates.

See:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29128/how-to-read-environment-variables-of-a-process

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you changed the environmental variable `PROJ` and your program's `PROJ` is not updating. When you call `PROJ = os.getenv('PROJ')`, it does not bind the variable `PROJ` to `os.getenv('PROJ')`, but just gets the value **at the current time**. You can wrap that in a function:

```
def updateProj():
    PROJ = os.getenv('PROJ')
```

Everytime you update the environment variable, you have to call `updateProj()` to update the global variable in your program.